# In regard to "little"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I place "little" after a linking verb "be"? For example, the effect of a quantity on the price is little.

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "The effect of quantity on the price is small."

Comment: Your example sounds weird to me for some reason, but no one would bat an eye at something like "When I was little, [...]".

Comment: Another common way of expressing it is to say that quantity has little effect on the price. One can say _small effect_, but _little_ is more colloquial.

Comment: 'Small' often for some reason works better than 'little'. One of the peculiarities of English. The fixed phrase 'little to none' bucks this trend; 'sales have been little to none for weeks' is idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are examples when it is used:
- there is little difference between us.
- what you say is little more than a joke.

your sentence could be rewritten like this:
- the effect of quantity on price is little more than nothing.